# Trying to get for loop to input all data at once into the structured output

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have my code currently  looping correctly, but I have trying to figure out how make it repeat first then place the data into the structured output. How is run now it does one input the place into the output and the does the same for the rest.

[I am trying to get mine similar to this, it ask how many you wish to and repeat that many time then put information into the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0D9O.png)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    int NumberofUserInputs;
                    string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider?";
                    string inputstring;

                    Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);

                    inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
                    NumberofUserInputs = int.Parse(inputstring);

                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
                    {
                        const float PI = (float)Math.PI;
                        float[] barSpecs = new float[11];
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar radius {0}:", i + 1);

                        barSpecs[0] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        barSpecs[2] = PI * (barSpecs[0]) * (barSpecs[0]); //area

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Bar heat conduction coefficient {0}:", i + 1);// lambda

                        barSpecs[1] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar length {0}:", i + 1); //length
                        barSpecs[3] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar change in time {0}:", i + 1); // Delta t
                        barSpecs[4] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar cold temp {0}:", i + 1); //T2
                        barSpecs[5] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar hot temp {0}:", i + 1);  //T1
                        barSpecs[6] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        barSpecs[7] = -((barSpecs[1] * barSpecs[2]) / barSpecs[3]) * (barSpecs[5] - barSpecs[6]) * barSpecs[4];
                        barSpecs[8] = barSpecs[7] / barSpecs[4];

                        if(
                        {
                            //structured output 
                            Console.WriteLine("Material        Lamda           T2      T1     Delta T    Length     Area      Delta Q/Delta t  ");
                            Console.WriteLine("          (cal/sec)/(C cm)     (C)     (C)     (Sec)      (cm)     (sq cm)     (cal/sec) ");
                            Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "ultimate", barSpecs[1], barSpecs[5], barSpecs[6], barSpecs[4], barSpecs[3], barSpecs[2], barSpecs[8]);
                            Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "Supreme", barSpecs[i], barSpecs[i], barSpecs[i + 6], barSpecs[i + 4], barSpecs[i + 3], barSpecs[i + 2], barSpecs[i + 8]);
                        }
                    }   
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Would like to continue? (Y = yes, N = no)");
            } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Jagged Arrays as well.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            int NumberofUserInputs;
            string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider?";
            string inputstring;
            Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);
            inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
            NumberofUserInputs = int.Parse(inputstring);

            float[][] barSpecs = new float[NumberofUserInputs][];

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
            {
                const float PI = (float)Math.PI;
                barSpecs[i] = new float[11];
                Console.WriteLine("Enter bar radius {0}:", i + 1);
                barSpecs[i][0] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                barSpecs[i][2] = PI * (barSpecs[i][0]) * (barSpecs[i][0]); //area

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Bar heat conduction coefficient {0}:", i + 1);// lamda
                barSpecs[i][1] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter bar length {0}:", i + 1); //length
                barSpecs[i][3] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter bar change in time {0}:", i + 1); // Delta t
                barSpecs[i][4] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter bar cold temp {0}:", i + 1); //T2
                barSpecs[i][5] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter bar hot temp {0}:", i + 1);  //T1
                barSpecs[i][6] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                barSpecs[i][7] = -((barSpecs[i][1] * barSpecs[i][2]) / barSpecs[i][3]) * (barSpecs[i][5] - barSpecs[i][6]) * barSpecs[i][4];
                barSpecs[i][8] = barSpecs[i][7] / barSpecs[i][4];

            }

            //    //structured output 
            Console.WriteLine("Material        Lamda           T2      T1     Delta T    Length     Area      Delta Q/Delta t  ");
            Console.WriteLine("          (cal/sec)/(C cm)     (C)     (C)     (Sec)      (cm)     (sq cm)     (cal/sec) ");
            for(int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "ultimate", barSpecs[i][1], barSpecs[i][5], barSpecs[i][6], barSpecs[i][4], barSpecs[i][3], barSpecs[i][2], barSpecs[i][8]);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Would like to continue? (Y = yes, N = no)");
    } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

store `barSpecs` at the end of each input loop, into a linked list, then at the end when the user enteres `N` then just loop through each list item, and then output the data in your format

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3 {
  class Program {
    static void Main() {
      List < float[] > bars = new List < float[] > ();
      do {
        try {
          bars.Clear();
          int NumberofUserInputs;
          string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider?";
          string inputstring;
          Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);
          inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
          NumberofUserInputs = int.Parse(inputstring);

          for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++) {

            const float PI = (float) Math.PI;
            float[] barSpecs = new float[11];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter bar radius {0}:", i + 1);
            barSpecs[0] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            barSpecs[2] = PI * (barSpecs[0]) * (barSpecs[0]); //area

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Bar heat conduction coefficient {0}:", i + 1); // lamda
            barSpecs[1] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter bar length {0}:", i + 1); //length
            barSpecs[3] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter bar change in time {0}:", i + 1); // Delta t
            barSpecs[4] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter bar cold temp {0}:", i + 1); //T2
            barSpecs[5] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter bar hot temp {0}:", i + 1); //T1
            barSpecs[6] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            barSpecs[7] = -((barSpecs[1] * barSpecs[2]) / barSpecs[3]) * (barSpecs[5] - barSpecs[6]) * barSpecs[4];
            barSpecs[8] = barSpecs[7] / barSpecs[4];

            bars.Add(barSpecs);

          }

        } catch (FormatException e) {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Would like to continue? (Y = yes, N = no)");
      } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
      Console.WriteLine("Material        Lamda           T2      T1     Delta T    Length     Area      Delta Q/Delta t  ");
      Console.WriteLine("          (cal/sec)/(C cm)     (C)     (C)     (Sec)      (cm)     (sq cm)     (cal/sec) ");
      foreach(var bar in bars) {
        Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "ultimate", bar[1], bar[5], bar[6], bar[4], bar[3], bar[2], bar[8]);
      }
      Console.ReadKey();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if need to print the structured output by last you just need to add an if statement like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    int NumberofUserInputs;
                    string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider?";
                    string inputstring;
                    Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);
                    inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
                    NumberofUserInputs = int.Parse(inputstring);

                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
                    {

                        const float PI = (float)Math.PI;
                        float[] barSpecs = new float[11];
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar radius {0}:", i + 1);
                        barSpecs[0] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        barSpecs[2] = PI * (barSpecs[0]) * (barSpecs[0]); //area

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Bar heat conduction coefficient {0}:", i + 1);// lamda
                        barSpecs[1] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar length {0}:", i + 1); //length
                        barSpecs[3] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar change in time {0}:", i + 1); // Delta t
                        barSpecs[4] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar cold temp {0}:", i + 1); //T2
                        barSpecs[5] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar hot temp {0}:", i + 1);  //T1
                        barSpecs[6] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        barSpecs[7] = -((barSpecs[1] * barSpecs[2]) / barSpecs[3]) * (barSpecs[5] - barSpecs[6]) * barSpecs[4];
                        barSpecs[8] = barSpecs[7] / barSpecs[4];
                        //SOLUTION******************************
                        if(i == NumberofUserInputs-1)
                        {

                            //structured output 
                            Console.WriteLine("Material        Lamda           T2      T1     Delta T    Length     Area      Delta Q/Delta t  ");
                            Console.WriteLine("          (cal/sec)/(C cm)     (C)     (C)     (Sec)      (cm)     (sq cm)     (cal/sec) ");
                            Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "ultimate", barSpecs[1], barSpecs[5], barSpecs[6], barSpecs[4], barSpecs[3], barSpecs[2], barSpecs[8]);
                            Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "Supreme", barSpecs[i], barSpecs[i], barSpecs[i + 6], barSpecs[i + 4], barSpecs[i + 3], barSpecs[i + 2], barSpecs[i + 8]);
                        }

                    }   
                    


                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Would like to continue? (Y = yes, N = no)");
            } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```